# Console.ReadLine in async method isn't blocking progression..?

Tags: c#

I need to know if there's a way to execute DownloadPage(result) without immediately proceeding to Console.ReadKey() in my main method.

What's happening is that DownloadPage fires, but after displaying "Would you like to save this to a .txt file? [Y/N]", the program ends after typing any key. I originally tried the entire method inside of GetPageHTML, but it keeps breaking as soon as I try to get user input.

I'm still learning C# and I don't know how to approach the problem and correct it. Can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Programming_Challenge_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter URL: ");
            string url = Console.ReadLine();

            GetPageHTML(url);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static async void GetPageHTML(string _url)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_url))
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    string title = Regex.Match(result, @"<title>\s*(.*?)\s*</title>").Groups[1].Value;
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading HTML...\n\nTitle: {0}\n\n{1}\n\n", title, result);
                    DownloadPage(result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error reading the url \"{0}\".", _url);
            }
        }

        static void DownloadPage(string _html)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to save this to a .txt file? [Y/N]");
            string saveFile = Console.ReadLine(); // CODE IS BREAKING HERE!

            if (saveFile.ToUpper() == "Y")
            {
                Console.Write("Please provide a file name: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(name + ".txt"))
                {
                    writer.Write(_html);
                    writer.Close();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("HTML has been saved to {0}.txt!", name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well yes - you're not waiting for the async operation to actually finish. You should declare the method to return `Task` instead, like this:

```
static async Task GetPageHtml(string _url)
```

and then wait for it in your `Main` method:

```
GetPageHtml(url).Wait();
```

Now *normally*, blocking for a task to complete synchronously like this is a bad idea because you could end up blocking the same thread that needs to do the work - but a console app's main thread doesn't have a synchronization context, so the continuations in the async method will run in a thread-pool thread... so this `Wait()` is safe.

Of course, this somewhat defeats part of the point of using async - but if you're just exploring async, that's fine.

In general, the *only* time an `async` method should be declared `void` is so that you can use it as an event handler.

Comment: would the `ConfigureAwait(…)` in console app give a perf boost?

Comment: @MikeMazmanyan: No, it basically wouldn't make any difference as there's no synchronization context to capture anyway. `ConfigureAwait` shouldn't be seen as a performance technique - it's used to make sure the continuation doesn't run on an inappropriate thread.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [JonSkeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) answer you can also use [StephenCleary's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) [AsyncEx Library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), then you can `await` your `GetPageHTML()` method. So your code will look like this:

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync(args));
}        

static async void MainAsync(string[] args)
{
  Console.Write("Enter URL: ");
  string url = Console.ReadLine();

  await GetPageHTML(url);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```